# TEMP_PART01 and C drive

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd

So we have a Samsung series 9 laptop and it has a 128 GB solid state drive, the problem we are having with it is that it has 4 partitions, one that's 100MB (who knows what for), one thats 40 GB (Primary Windows partition), 60 GB partition (TEMP_PART01) and a microsoft office one.

The primary windows partition only has less than, 30 MB left, we want to increase this space, I know that I could just move everything to temp_part01 but we are not quite sure on it. What we are thinking of doing is deleting this partition all together and extending the windows volume.

The problem is that the extra partition has 55.7 remaining out of 59.7 GB, which means there is something on it, but it shows up with nothing when we go into it, when we change the settings to show hidden files, but still nothing, I then used CMD to list all the files using `dir d:` and still no files. So would it be safe to delete it and extend the windows volume? Or what should I do?

Here's a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to enable the switch that shows hidden, system, and operating system files (hit `Alt`, then go to the View > Folder Options menu). That will give you a better idea of what's on that partition. If it's one physical drive, I'd suggest deleting the D: partition and extending the C: drive, just as you considered.

Comment: So there wouldn't be something on there that might stuff up something if I delete it right?

Comment: Probably not. But the only way to know is to unhide everything and see for yourself what is there.

Comment: It has the pagefile in it.

Comment: You can change the page file size to zero, reboot into Safe Mode, repartition, then change the page file to System Managed on the C: drive and reboot again.

Comment: Thats pretty much what I did, want to put it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you'll need to enable the switch that shows hidden, system, and operating system files (hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then go to the `View` > `Folder Options` menu).

That will give you a better idea of what's on that partition. If it's one physical drive, I'd suggest deleting the D: partition and extending the C: drive, just as you considered.

In your comments, you pointed out that the page file is the only thing there, so you can change the page file size to zero, reboot into Safe Mode, repartition, then change the page file to System Managed on the C: drive and reboot again.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was exactly what I did earlier today after realising what was there.

Comment: Very pleased that it was easy to solve.

Comment: I was happy that it was easy to solve as well.